# Can't connect to local Machine IP through TCP From Arduino Uno using SIM900 Shield

Tags: python, tcp, arduino, at-command, gprs

So you have a basic understanding of the parts im using, I have:

- Arduino Uno
- Seeed Studio GPRS Shield v2.0 (http://www.seeedstudio.com/wiki/GPRS_Shield_V2.0)
- Ultimate GPS for Adafruit V3.3 (https://www.adafruit.com/products/746?gclid=Cj0KEQjw3-W5BRCymr_7r7SFt8cBEiQAsLtM8qn4SCfVWIvAwW-x9Mu-FLeB6hLmVd0PAPVU8IAXXPgaAtaC8P8HAQ)

Here is my problem: 
I have tested the Arduino stacked with the GPRS shield, and it works fine with regards to accessing the internet through TCP, sending SMS, etc.. However, my application requires me to send GPS data from the adafruit GPS to a web server that I have already coded with Django and postgresql. The backend is set up.

I need to send the data from the Uno (client) to my laptop (server), which I coded in python (This is just to check whether it is creating a connection):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import socket
# import postgres database functions 

TCP_IP = '192.168.1.112'
TCP_PORT = 10000
BUFFER_SIZE = 40

server_address = (TCP_IP,TCP_PORT)
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
print 'Socket created.'

# Bind socket to TCP server and port
try:
    s.bind(server_address)
except socket.error as msg:
    print 'Bind failed. Error Code : ' + str(msg[0]) + ' Message ' + msg[1]
    sys.exit()
print 'Socket Bind Complete.'

# Start Listening on socket
s.listen(1)                                             # Puts socket into server mode
print 'Listening on port: ', TCP_PORT 

# Now Keep Talking with the client
while (1):
    # Wait to accept a connection
    conn, addr = s.accept()                                 # Wait for incoming connection with accept()
    print 'Connection address:', addr

    data = conn.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)

    if not data: break

    print "recieved data: data", data

    conn.send(data) #echo
conn.close()
```

I dont think there is a problem with this. From this I will post data to my postgreSQL database. However, When I try to use AT commands on the SIM900 module to connect to the server using port 10000, I cannot connect:

```
AT+CIPSHUT

SHUT OK
AT+CGATT?

+CGATT: 1

OK
AT+CIPMUX=0

OK
AT+CSTT="fast.t-mobile.com","",""

OK
AT+CIICR

OK
AT+CIFSR

6.60.94.49
AT+CIPSTART="TCP","192.168.1.112,"10000"

OK

STATE: TCP CLOSED

CONNECT FAIL
```

I have tried connecting through TCP and replaced the AT+CIPSTART line with the below statement and it worked, so I know TCP works:

```
AT+CIPSTART="TCP","www.vishnusharma.com", "80"
```

Is the IP i'm using wrong? I'm new to this, but if it makes a difference, im using Ubuntu 16.04 partitioned on my Mac OSX. I have also checked the APN for T-mobile and it seems fine.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IP you're using is inside a [NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) since it starts with 192.168. Unless you have a private apn with the mobile operator you're using, you won't be able to reach your Ubuntu from a public IP. Your ISP gives you a public IP address which ir administrated by your router, so if you want this to work, you'll have to do a [port forwarding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding) from your router to your Ubuntu.

To do the port forwarding you have to get in the router's configuration page (Typically 192.168.1.1 but depends on the model) an there you'll have to redirect the port XXX to 192.168.1.112:10000. After that you have to obtain your public IP (`curl ifconfig.co`) and use it to access from the SIM900.

Comment: Thank you that is definitely what I needed!

Comment: For anybody looking for reference, I had 2 problems: 1) The IP i was using was inside a NAT, meaning it was using a private IP given by DHCP of my router. I had to use port forwarding to connect to my routers public IP address and use the port specified in my routers settings for port forwarding. 2) I had to get rid of the firewall blocking my ports by using the command  - sudo ufw allow 10000/tcp.

Answer (score 0):

First of all as a suggestion, you can combine the two shields by using SIM908 (unless you are getting more precision on your GPS shield). Since your TCP connection is working, I bet that the port 10000 on your ubuntu is blocked by the firewall. You can first try to turn off your firewall and see if it works. If it did not worked its something else. If it worked, **turn on** your firewall and then unblock the tcp port using the following command:

```
sudo ufw allow 10000/tcp
```

Comment: Thank you for your post, but disabling the firewall didn't work, any other ideas?

Comment: When you are running your application (python code) try to see if the tcp port is active and is listening. you can do that with with some command like: 

netstat -nlp | grep 10000

Comment: When I run that command as Admin I get: tcp    0    0 192.168.1.112:10000    0.0.0.0:*        LISTEN    5458/python. Does that mean the port is active if it shows up as LISTEN?

Comment: yeah thats pretty much what it is and the fact that the process name belongs to a python script confirms that the port is opened by your application. I cant think of any other solution at the moment sorry!

Comment: For the above command, how to you reverse it and reblock the port? I checked my ports on ShieldsUP and all ports were shown as stealth even after turning off the firewall. Any idea how to make them open?